# arrangements- married couple

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From 10 married couples, we want to select a group of 6 people that is not allowed to contain a married couple.

(a) How many choices are there?

(b) How many choices are there if the group must also consist of 3 men and 3 women?

I did $\binom{10}{6}\mathbb{2}^6$ for (a) i.e choosing 6 couples out of 10 * choosing one member from each couple;

How to proceed for (b)?

Comment: Select the 3 men, $\binom{10}{3}$ then select 3 women excluding the 3 men's wife $\binom{7}{3}$. Multiply these

Comment: oh, is that all?, okay understood

Comment: Another approach is $\binom{10}{6}\times\binom{6}{3}$. Select the 6 couples first, then select 3 of these to take the man from, take the woman from the unchosen 3.

Comment: okay, understood

Comment: Counting problems should be tagged combinatorics.

Comment: okay will do it:)

Answer (score 1):

In this post, I offer an alternative solution. The reasoning used is essentially the same as the reasoning we use to derive the $\binom{n}{r}$ formula, and so is there is no preference between either of these methods.

a)

$$
\frac{20\cdot18\cdot16\cdot14\cdot12\cdot10}{6!}=13,440
$$
Your method works perfectly well; I merely offer an alternative solution. For every person you select, there are two people you can no longer pick—the person you selected, and their partner. Also, dividing by $6!$ allows us to deal with the duplicates.

b)
$$
\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5}{3!\cdot3!}=4200
$$
Here, we have to select $3$ men out of a group of $10$, hence the $10\cdot9\cdot8$. Once, you have selected the $3$ men, you have to pick $3$ women; however, these women cannot be from a couple. Therefore, there are $7$ possibilities, then $6$, and then $5$. As you choose from the groups of men and women, there are $3!$ ways to end up with the same group of $3$ men/women. Therefore, we divide by $3!$ twice.

Comment: okay, different approach:)